# Adding class to a foreach loop every N times

Tags: php, html

I have an users list, each user is wrapped by a div, this way

```
<div class="users">
    <div>user 1 content</div>
    <div>user 2 content</div>
    <div>user 3 content</div>
    <div>user 4 content</div>...
</div>
```

then all are displayed this way:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
...... and so on
```

divs numbers **1,4,7,10..** should have a class called **class_left** for instance,
divs numbers **2,5,8,11,14..** should have a class called **class_center** and
divs numbers **3,6,9,12,15...** should have a class called **class_right**

I am not quite sure how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: show us the code you are using

Comment: If there are 3 divs, you should be only be using `% 3` and seeing if the remainder is `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by using `modulus` operator with 3.

Here is a pseudo code:

```
if(div_number % 3 ==1)
   class = class_left;
else if(div_number % 3 == 2)
   class = class_center;
else
   class=class_right;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're using your code, but you can use modulus operator in this way: if column number modulus 3 is 1 then you're on the left, else if the result is 2 you're on the center, else with result equal 0, you're on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `$data` is your array of data:

```
<?php $aligns = array('right', 'left', 'center'); ?>

<div class="users">
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
        <div class="class_<?php echo $aligns[$key % 3]; ?>">
            <?php var_dump($value); ?> // User X's Content          
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i = 1;
$last = 100;

for ($i =1; $i<$last; $i=+3) {
    echo "<div class='class_left'>user ".$i." content</div>";
    echo "<div class='class_center'>user ".($i+1)." content</div>";
    echo "<div class='class_right'>user ".($i+2)." content</div>";
}
```

Or if you want a function that will take the number and return the class name you should try something like:

```
    function getClass($num) {
    if (!$num % 3) {
        return 'class_right';
    }

    if (!($num + 1) % 3) {
        return 'class_center';
    }

    if (!($num + 2) % 3) {
        return 'class_left'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this way:

```
var curr = 0;
users.forEach(user){
      curr++;
      switch(curr){
        case 1:
          user.class = 'class_left';
        case 2:
          user.class = 'class_center';
        case 3:
          user.class = 'class_right';
          curr = 0;
      }
}
```

This is only javascript example. Please use your language.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for any number of `div` elements per row. (If you set `$divsPerRow` to 2, `class_center` will not be used. If you set it to 1, neither will `class_right`.)

```
$divsPerRow = 3;
$users = range(1, $divsPerRow * 3);

echo '<div class="users">' . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
    $class = "left";
    $column = $i % $divsPerRow + 1;
    if ($column > 1) {
        $class = ($column == $divsPerRow) ? "right" : "center";
    }
    echo '<div class="class_' . $class . '">user ' . $users[$i]
        . ' content</div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score -1):

What is you looking for is:

```
(i-1)%3 == 0
```